# Gnuplot plot specific lines from data file

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file with 24 lines and 3 columns. How can I plot only the data from specific lines, e.g. 3,7,9,14,18,21?
Now I use the following command

```
plot 'xy.dat' using 0:2:3:xticlabels(1) with boxerrorbars ls 2
```

which plots all 24 lines.

I tried the `every` command but couldn't figure out a way that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Untested, but something like this

```
plot "<(sed -n -e 3p -e 7p -e 9p xy.dat)" using ...
```

Another option may be to annotate your datafile, if as it seems, it contains multiple datasets. Let's say you created your datafile like this:

```
1 2 3
2 1 3 # SetA
2 7 3 # SetB
2 2 1 # SetA SetB SetC
```

Then if you wanted just `SetA` you would use this `sed` command in the plot statement

```
sed -ne '/SetA/s/#.*//p' xy.dat
2 1 3
2 2 1
```

That says...*"in general, don't print anything (`-n`), but, if you do see a line containing `SetA`, delete the hash sign and everything after it and print the line"*.

or if you wanted `SetB`, you would use

```
sed -ne '/SetB/s/#.*//p' xy.dat
2 7 3
2 2 1
```

or if you wanted the *whole* data file, but stripped of our comments

```
sed -e 's/#.*//' xy.dat
```

If you wanted `SetB` and `SetC`, use

```
sed -ne '/Set[BC]/s/#.*//p' xy.dat
2 7 3 
2 2 1
```

Answer (score 2):

If the lines you want have something in common that you can evaluate, e.g. the label in column 1 begins with an "a"

```
 plot dataf using (strcol(1)[1:1] eq "a" ? $0 : NaN):2:xticslabel(1)
```

you can just skip these lines by letting the using statement return "NaN".

This here is an ugly hack you can use in case the desired line numbers are just arbitrary:

```
linnum = " 1 3 7 12 16 21 "
plot dataf using (strstrt(linnum," ".int($0)." ") != 0 ? $0 : NaN):2
```

`strstrt(a,b)` returns the position of string b in string a, zero if it does not appear. I add the two spaces to make the line numbers unique.

But I would recommend using an external program to preprocess the data in that case, see the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a solution with `every`. Since you want to plot `with boxerrorbars` it can be done in a `plot for`-loop.

- no external tools, i.e. gnuplot-only and  hence platform-independent
- no strictly increasing line numbers, but arbitrary sequence of lines possible

**Script:**

```
### plot only certain lines appearing in a list
reset session

# create some random test data
set print $Data
do for [i=1:24] {
    print sprintf("line%02d  %g  %g", i, rand(0)*5+1, rand(0)*0.5)
}
set print

myLines   = "3 7 9 14 18 21"
myLine(i) = int(word(myLines,i)-1)

set offsets 0.5,0.5,0,0
set style fill solid 0.3
set boxwidth 0.6
set xtics out
set key noautotitle
set yrange [0:]

plot for [i=1:words(myLines)] $Data u (i):2:3:xtic(1) \
         every ::myLine(i)::myLine(i) w boxerrorbars lc "blue"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Very elegant... nice work!